# count even length words in vectors

Tags: c++, console-application

I have 2 problems.

1) `cout << v_setir.capacity();` is not returns the correct number.

2) *I want to count of the words which lengths are even.* and I should do it with vectors.

Here is my codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int say = 0;

    cout << "Setiri daxil edin: ";
    string setir;
    getline(cin, setir);

    vector<string> v_setir;
    string ifadeler;
    istringstream yig(setir);

    while (yig >> ifadeler)
        v_setir.push_back(setir);

    // First problem
    cout << v_setir.capacity() << endl;

    // Second problem
/*  for (size_t i = 0; i < v_setir.capacity(); i++)
    {
        if (v_setir[i].size() % 2 == 0)
            say += 1;
    }
    cout << "Uzunlugu cut olan sozerin sayi: " << say << endl;*/

    return 0;
}
```

For example, if I enter this string line it returns "6" (why I don't know):

> *hi hello how are you*

What is wrong? my brain stopped and I couldn't determine what is the wrong in my code and/or algorithm.

Please, help me to solve these problems.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `cout << v_setir.capacity()`; is not returns the correct number.

Use `vector::size` as the number of the element in the vector.

2) I want to count of the words which lengths are even. and I should do it with vectors.

Firstly you should use `v_setir.size()` instead of `v_setir.capacity()` in your loop as the condition.
And secondly, why not you cout the string to check whether it's length is even or not? Actually you put 5 'hi hello how are you' into the vector.

I think you want to put every single words into the vector, but not the whole sentence. If that use `v_setir.push_back(ifadeler);` instead of `v_setir.push_back(setir);`

Comment: very very big thanks :) 
I solved my problem changing `v_setir.push_back(ifadeler);` instead of `v_setir.push_back(setir);`

P.S. I changed loop condition as `v_setir.size()` after post this question :D 

Thanks. Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

`capacity()` is the currently allocated space not the count of elements in the vector. Use: `size()` instead

See:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size

Your loop should work fine now, but you can also take a look at the example [there](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) which does something similar for integer divisible by 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can count  even-length words with `std::count_if`:

```
#include <algorithm>

int even_words = std::count_if(v_setir.begin(), v_setir.end(), [] (const string& str) { return str.size() % 2 == 0; });
```

Comment: thanks. but it did not solve my problem. it returns " 0 ". however I gave 3 *even word*.

Answer (score 1):

`vector::capacity` gives capacity of vector (how much elements it can store). Here, you want to calculate number of strings whose length is even. You need to iterate over the strings and count the strings whose length is even.

Answer (score 1):

**`std::vector::capacity` >= `std::vector::size`**

- The capacity is the maximum number of elements the vector can currently hold.
- The size is the number of elements in the vector.